# How to merge two CSV files having same value for two column fields using python?

Tags: pandas, data-science

The first CSV file.

```
    DATE            TIME      ENG-1  ENG-2    ENG-3  ENG-4   ENG-5   ENG-6
'01 10 2016'    '06:35:00'  0.28596 0.29029 0.28756 0.28571 0.30868 0.14109
'01 10 2016'    '06:40:00'  0.44193 0.45012 0.44324 0.44423 0.46907 0.21463
'01 10 2016'    '06:45:00'  0.62864 0.64037 0.62642 0.63543 0.66269 0.31124
'01 10 2016'    '06:50:00'  0.80956 0.83893 0.80395 0.83088 0.85561 0.39706
'01 10 2016'    '06:55:00'  1.03745 1.06965 1.03274 1.06828 1.09404 0.51961
'01 10 2016'    '07:00:00'  1.27753 1.32139 1.27205 1.31855 1.3468  0.64307
'01 10 2016'    '07:05:00'  1.47166 1.52537 1.45165 1.52041 1.54714 0.74423
```

The Second CSV file

```
   DATE            TIME     A    B  C   D
'01 10 2016'    '06:00:00'  27  74  0   4
'01 10 2016'    '06:30:00'  27  74  1.9 4
'01 10 2016'    '07:00:00'  27  74  0   4
'01 10 2016'    '07:30:00'  28  70  7.4 4
'01 10 2016'    '08:00:00'  28  70  9.3 4
```

I want to combine these two CSV into the third CSV file only taking those value for which the Date and Time value matches.

The Resultant combined CSV file should be like this.

```
    DATE            TIME      ENG-1    ENG-2    ENG-3  ENG-4   ENG-5   ENG-6   A    B   C   D
 '01 10 2016'    '07:00:00'  1.27753 1.32139 1.27205 1.31855 1.3468  0.64307  27   74   0   4
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with default `inner` join with parameter `on`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['DATE','TIME'])
print (df)
           DATE        TIME    ENG-1    ENG-2    ENG-3    ENG-4   ENG-5  \
0  '01 10 2016'  '07:00:00'  1.27753  1.32139  1.27205  1.31855  1.3468   

     ENG-6   A   B    C  D  
0  0.64307  27  74  0.0  4
```

If only `DATE` and `TIME` columns (for join) are in both `DataFrames` and all another columns names are different, `on` can be omit too:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print (df)
           DATE        TIME    ENG-1    ENG-2    ENG-3    ENG-4   ENG-5  \
0  '01 10 2016'  '07:00:00'  1.27753  1.32139  1.27205  1.31855  1.3468   

     ENG-6   A   B    C  D  
0  0.64307  27  74  0.0  4
```

Also is necessary same `dtype`s of columns for join, else no match.